# Casting issue in JAVA

Tags: java, casting, stack, double

I am having trouble casting from a string to a char then to a double. I'm trying to calculate a simple expression 1+2 but when I pop it from a stack its 50.0 and 49.0 respectively. Then adds to 99.0. My code is below.

The expression is '1+2'

```
public static double calculate (String expression){
        Stack<Character> calc = new Stack();
        expression.replaceAll("\\s+","") ;
        double result = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++){
            calc.push((char) expression.charAt(i));
        }

        double one = (double) calc.pop();
        char expr = calc.pop();
        double two = (double) calc.pop();


        if(expr == '-'){
            result = one - (1*two);
        } else if (expr == '+'){
            result = one + (1*two);
        }

        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Your code will only work with numbers 0-9.

Comment: @celticminstrel yes its just a simple calculator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that when you do a direct cast to a number like this

```
(double) calc.pop();
```

...you are actually getting the ***ascii*** values of the ***characters*** `'1'` (ascii `49`) and `'2'` (ascii `50`).

You need to ***parse*** the character. Something like this will work:

```
Double.parseDouble(calc.pop().toString());
```